# How to get accurate gps location in android

Tags: android, gps

I am developing an app where I need to show the exact and the most accurate location in maps. I tried using GPS_PROVIDER which gives 100mtrs distance from the location. can you guys please suggest me how to get the exact location.

here is my code

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
{

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    double lat,longit;

    private final float MIN_DISTANCE = 6; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, MIN_DISTANCE, this);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,50,5,this);

        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


        GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

        if(gpsTracker.canGetLocation)
        {
            lat = gpsTracker.latitude;
            longit = gpsTracker.longitude;

            System.out.println("latitude" +lat + "longitude" +longit);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "latitude" +lat + "longitude" +longit, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        try
        {
            initializeMap();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void initializeMap() 
    {

        if(googleMap == null)
        {

            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            /*double latitude =  17.385044;
            double longitude = 78.486671;*/

            String abc = "Hello Maps";

            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, longit)).title(abc);

            //MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(17.426836, 78.549902)).title(abc);

            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));


            if(googleMap == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry unable to create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initializeMap();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(location.hasAccuracy())
        {
            return;
        }
        if(location.getAccuracy()>5)
        {
            return;

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

GPSTracker:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener
    {
        private final Context mContext;

        //flag for GPS Status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        //flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        boolean canGetLocation = false;

        Location location;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;

        //The minimum distance to change updates in metters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 metters

        //The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

        //Declaring a Location Manager
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public GPSTracker(Context context) 
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();
        }

        public Location getLocation()
        {
            try
            {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                //getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                //getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
                {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                }
                else
                {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;

                    //First get location from Network Provider
                    if (isNetworkEnabled)
                    {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("Network", "Network");

                        if (locationManager != null)
                        {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinates();
                        }
                    }

                    //if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled)
                    {
                        if (location == null)
                        {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                            if (locationManager != null)
                            {
                                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                updateGPSCoordinates();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error : Location", "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
            }

            return location;
        }

        public void updateGPSCoordinates()
        {
            if (location != null)
            {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Stop using GPS listener
         * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
         */

        public void stopUsingGPS()
        {
            if (locationManager != null)
            {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         */
        public double getLatitude()
        {
            if (location != null)
            {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         */
        public double getLongitude()
        {
            if (location != null)
            {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            return longitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
         */
        public boolean canGetLocation()
        {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog
         */
        public void showSettingsAlert()
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            //Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("LAT Long");

            //Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS Message");

            //On Pressing Setting button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {   
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            //On pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {   
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
         * @return null or List<Address>
         */
        public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context)
        {
            if (location != null)
            {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
                try 
                {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    return addresses;
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Try to get AddressLine
         * @return null or addressLine
         */
        public String getAddressLine(Context context)
        {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

                return addressLine;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Try to get Locality
         * @return null or locality
         */
        public String getLocality(Context context)
        {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String locality = address.getLocality();

                return locality;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Try to get Postal Code
         * @return null or postalCode
         */
        public String getPostalCode(Context context)
        {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

                return postalCode;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Try to get CountryName
         * @return null or postalCode
         */
        public String getCountryName(Context context)
        {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String countryName = address.getCountryName();

                return countryName;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {   
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        {   
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {   
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
        {   
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
        {
            return null;
        }


}
```

please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you wait for the GPS to have a proper lock? I also suggest changing your `if (isNetworkEnabled)` followed by `if (isGPSEnabled)` to `if (isGPSEnabled) { ... } else if (isNetworkEnabled) { ... }`.

Comment: @PLPeeters Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: You have to wait for a while for your GPS chip to pinpoint your location; it usually doesn't happen instantly.

Comment: @PLPeeters Yeah I have waited .But no result

Comment: you should not create service by calling new operator ... is this the code from infamously bad androidhive's tutorial?

Comment: @Selvin Yeah I integrated this from androidhive of some part. Do we need to add any calculation part of GPS to get accurate location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the actual state of things, you will never get a GPS location after you have a network location. `location` will never be `null` in your second condition, because it was already set by the network provider. In short, your app is just never fetching the user's location from the GPS provider (see comment below).

```
if (isNetworkEnabled)
{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

    Log.d("Network", "Network");

    if (locationManager != null)
    {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        updateGPSCoordinates();
    }
}

//if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
if (isGPSEnabled)
{
    // Location will most likely never be null here, since it was fetched first by the network provider above
    if (location == null)
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

        if (locationManager != null)
        {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            updateGPSCoordinates();
        }
    }
}
```

Most importantly, this code is in the wrong place, it should go in the `onLocationChanged(Location location)` method so it runs every time there is a location update. Leaving it there to get a preliminary location can be interesting though. I suggest you change the code to something like this:

```
//if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
if (isGPSEnabled)
{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

        if (locationManager != null)
        {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            updateGPSCoordinates();
        }
    }
} else if (isNetworkEnabled) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

    Log.d("Network", "Network");

    if (locationManager != null)
    {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        updateGPSCoordinates();
    }
}

// ...

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{ 
    this.location = location;
    updateGPSCoordinates();
}
```

Comment: I am able to get my location . But here the requirement is to get the accurate location like I need to show my office exactly in maps. My lead said that we have some gps calculation . If we calculate we will get the accurate location he said. can u please tell that

Comment: It will fetch the GPS location correctly if your remove the `if (location == null)` condition.

Comment: So without if condition I should execute you are saying right?

Comment: I removed and executed.but not showing accurate value. Showing very far from my place

Comment: I've edited my answer, I forgot one huge problem in your solution, which is the fact you're not using your listener...